# Преобразовать массив php для Телеграм бот

Tags: массивы, telegram-bot, бот

Есть готовый массив.

```
$arr = [
  ["text" => "andijon", "callback_data" => "and"],
  ["text" => "namangan", "callback_data" => "nam"],
  ["text" => "toshkent", "callback_data" => "tosh"],
  ["text" => "fargona", "callback_data" => "far"],
  ["text" => "samarqand", "callback_data" => "sam"],
  ["text" => "buxoro", "callback_data" => "bux"],
  ["text" => "qashqadaryo", "callback_data" => "qash"],
  ["text" => "surxondaryo", "callback_data" => "sur"],
  ["text" => "xorazm", "callback_data" => "xor"],
  ["text" => "qoraqalpogiston", "callback_data" => "qor"],
  ["text" => "jizzax", "callback_data" => "jiz"],
  ["text" => "sirdaryo", "callback_data" => "sir"],
  ["text" => "navoiy", "callback_data" => "nav"],
  ["text" => "toshkent_viloyati", "callback_data" => "toshv"],
];
```

Нужно изменит на этот:

```
$arr = [
    [
        ['text' =>  "and", 'callback_data' => "andijon"],
        ['text' =>  "nam", 'callback_data' => "namangan"],
        ['text' =>  "tosh", 'callback_data' => "toshkent"],
    ],
    [
        ['text' =>  "far", 'callback_data' => "fargona"],
        ['text' =>  "sam", 'callback_data' => "samarqand"],
        ['text' =>  "bux", 'callback_data' => "buxoro"],
    ],
    [
        ['text' =>  "qash", 'callback_data' => "qashqadaryo"],
        ['text' =>  "sur", 'callback_data' => "surxondaryo"],
        ['text' =>  "xor", 'callback_data' => "xorazm"],
    ],
    [
        ['text' =>  "qor", 'callback_data' => "qoraqalpogiston"],
        ['text' =>  "jiz", 'callback_data' => "jizzax"],
        ['text' =>  "sir", 'callback_data' => "sirdaryo"],
    ],
    [
        ['text' =>  "nav", 'callback_data' => "navoiy"],
        ['text' =>  "toshv", 'callback_data' => "toshkent_viloyati"],
    ]
];
```

Comment: обычный foreach и array_chunk()

Comment: спасибо, я не думал что это очень простой код

Answer (score 0):

```php
$arr = [
    ["text" => "andijon", "callback_data" => "and"],
    ["text" => "namangan", "callback_data" => "nam"],
    ["text" => "toshkent", "callback_data" => "tosh"],
    ["text" => "fargona", "callback_data" => "far"],
    ["text" => "samarqand", "callback_data" => "sam"],
    ["text" => "buxoro", "callback_data" => "bux"],
    ["text" => "qashqadaryo", "callback_data" => "qash"],
    ["text" => "surxondaryo", "callback_data" => "sur"],
    ["text" => "xorazm", "callback_data" => "xor"],
    ["text" => "qoraqalpogiston", "callback_data" => "qor"],
    ["text" => "jizzax", "callback_data" => "jiz"],
    ["text" => "sirdaryo", "callback_data" => "sir"],
    ["text" => "navoiy", "callback_data" => "nav"],
    ["text" => "toshkent_viloyati", "callback_data" => "toshv"],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $button) {
    $text = $button['text'];
    $callbackData = $button['callback_data'];

    $result[]['text'] = $callbackData;
    $result[]['callback_data'] = $text;
}
$arr = array_chunk($arr, 3);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => andijon
                    [callback_data] => and
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => namangan
                    [callback_data] => nam
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => toshkent
                    [callback_data] => tosh
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => fargona
                    [callback_data] => far
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => samarqand
                    [callback_data] => sam
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => buxoro
                    [callback_data] => bux
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => qashqadaryo
                    [callback_data] => qash
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => surxondaryo
                    [callback_data] => sur
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => xorazm
                    [callback_data] => xor
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => qoraqalpogiston
                    [callback_data] => qor
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => jizzax
                    [callback_data] => jiz
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [text] => sirdaryo
                    [callback_data] => sir
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [text] => navoiy
                    [callback_data] => nav
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [text] => toshkent_viloyati
                    [callback_data] => toshv
                )

        )

)
```